# How does apps like norton security and jio security gets to know about which URL I'm loading in my chrome browser?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

Apps like norton security and jio security gets to know about which URL I'm loading in my chrome browser, but how do they get this info what permission they are using .

---

**They works as follows ,**

1. Runs in the background all the time
2. Whenever i load an malicious url suddenly a pop-up come up and warn me not to load that site

Answer (score -1):

We can get Bookmarks, History,Searches like information using content provider

```
content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks
content://com.android.chrome.browser/history
content://com.android.chrome.browser/searches
```

For that we need the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

current page is the first element of history.

Comment: Is it possible that history is updated before the actual page is loaded?